# When executing bash script file it shows a syntax error

Tags: shell

This is my code :
Where i need to check weather X is grater than Y or less than Y or equal to Y

```
 #! /bin/bash
    
    read x 
    read y

if (( $x -lt $y  ))
then
    echo "X is less than Y "
elif (( $x -eq $y ));
then
    echo "X is equal to Y "
else
    echo "X is greater than Y" 

fi
```

I Got this kind of error:

> Solution.sh: line 6: ((: 5 -lt 2  : syntax error in expression (error token is "2  ")
> Solution.sh: line 9: ((: 5 -eq 2 : syntax error in expression (error token is "2 ")

It will show syntax error but I don't know what is error in this code?

Comment: The comparision operator in numeric context is `<`, not `-lt`.

Comment: Read the bash man-page, in particular the chapter titled _ARITHMETIC EVALUATION_, which explains all the operators available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
    read x 
    read y

if (( $x < $y  ))
then
    echo "X is less than Y "
elif (( $x == $y ));
then
    echo "X is equal to Y "
else
    echo "X is greater than Y" 

fi
```

Comment: Greater than(>), less than(<) and double equals( == ) is use for when you are working with string here i want to work with numbers.